# How to use getchildfragmentmanager without extending fragment class?

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2, supportmapfragment

I am using

```
class baseactivity extends Activity
{
    //some stuffs is here, so i cannot Extend Fragment  
}
class activity extends baseactivity
{
    GoogleMap map=((MapFragment) getFragmanentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    if(map!=null)
        Log.e("map is not null","map was unable to initialize");//printing till kitkat version
    else
        Log.e("map is initialize","successfully initialize");//printing in lollipop
}
```

It's working fine till kitkat but it's `null` in lollipop version I know that I can use getchildfragmentmanager but I cannot extend fragment class cause my project is almost completed so I cannot make big changes. 
Help me without extending fragment class.

Updated code which also not working for me

```
class Baseactivity extends Activty
{
    //some stuff
}
class parent extends Baseactivity implements OnMapLoadedCallback
{
    GoogleMap map;
    void oncreate(Bundle savedIntanceState)
    {
        MapFragment mapfragment;
        mapfragment.setOnMapLoaderCallback(this);
        //map.addmarker.
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLoaded()
    {
        map=((MapFragment)getMapFragment.findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you attaching the fragment to the activity? Commit the transaction, then use getMapAsync like ianhanniballake says, then you will receive your GoogleMap instance directly in the callback.

Comment: I cannot extend fragment to the activity cause i am extending BaseActivity which is base class of Activity and BaseActivity have some stuff which i have to use in my main Activity.

Answer (score 2):

Per the [getMap() documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html#getMap()):

> **This method is deprecated.** Use [getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback)](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html#getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)) instead. The callback method provides you with a GoogleMap instance guaranteed to be non-null and ready to be used.

`getMap()` is not guaranteed to return a non-null map as it takes some time to prepare - use an [OnMapReadyCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback.html) and do your map initialization steps in the callback there.

Comment: I am getting  NullpointerException at map.setOnMapLoadedCallback(this)  .

Comment: Same Problem with me also, any solution ?

Comment: @Nitin - you're code has 'map' as a 'GoogleMap', but 'setOnMapLoadedCallback()' is a method of 'MapFragment'. Can you post your updated code that you are trying to run?

Comment: class Baseactivity extends Activty
{
 //some stuff
}
class parent extends Baseactivity implements OnMapLoadedCallback
{
 GoogleMap map;
 void oncreate(Bundle savedIntanceState)
 {
  MapFragment mapfragment;
  mapfragment.setOnMapLoaderCallback(this);
  //map.addmarker.
 }
 
 @Override
 public void onMapLoaded()
 {
  map=((MapFragment)getMapFragment.findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
 }
}

Comment: It doesn't look like you are actually using `getMapAsync()` anywhere in your code. Make sure you are using at least Google Play Services 6.5 and then actually use `getMapAsync()`